# Docker-compose override not overriding connection string

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have an ASP.NET web app which connects to a SQL database.

In `appsettings.Development.json` the connection string is defined as

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=WebRecipes-LocalDev;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0"
  }
```

In my `docker-compose.yml` file I get the latest `mssql-server-linux`

```
services:
  sql.data:
      image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

  webrecipes.api:
     image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webrecipesapi
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: src/WebRecipes.Api/Dockerfile
```

In `docker-compose.override.yml` I set the username and password for `sql.data` and override the connection string for my asp.net core app

```
services:
  sql.data:
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Pass@word
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "5533:1433"

  webrecipes.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44302
      - ConnectionString=Server=sql.data;database=WebRecipes-LocalDev;User Id=sa;Password=Pass@word
    ports:
      - "2282:80"
      - "44302:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
    depends_on:
      - sql.data
```

- **Edit:** I also tried setting the connection string to:

`- ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=sql.data;database=WebRecipes-LocalDev;User Id=sa;Password=Pass@word`

> When I run the app and it first tries to hit the db I get error saying LocalDb is not supported as it is using the connection string defined in `appsettings.Development.json`

Can anyone help with this? I don't see what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Is it possible to use a local appsettings.Development.json that you map as a volume in the docker-compose.yml? This way you are sure that your app will use this version

Comment: `ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection` should work. What issue did you get when using it? Try to return `public IActionResult Index()        {            return Ok($"ConnectionString = { _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")} ");
        }` to check whether it return expected value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core official docs on [environment variable configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environment-variables-configuration-provider) has the following explanation:

> When working with hierarchical keys in environment variables, a colon separator (:) may not work on all platforms (for example, Bash). A double underscore (__) is supported by all platforms and is automatically replaced by a colon.

Answer (score 23):

Using double underscores worked for me

ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=sql.data;database=WebRecipes-LocalDev;User Id=sa;Password=Pass@word